# wrapping text in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

is there any way to wrap the text in photopshop ?

I have to add new lines to format the paragraph. I was wondering if I can wrap it by dragging a container.

I use Photoshop CS5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a text box by dragging out a rectangle with the text tool and inserting your text. The text will wrap within the box.
To resize the box, click in the text and the text box will be displayed. Hover the mouse over one of the corners until the cursor changes and you can then resize the box and the text will wrap within it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if you can do this, because its not a word processor.

Moving the text to the next line actually gives you more control over the placement of your text.

If you are creating a new text box for a new line, that is not needed, just press ENTER when you get to the end of the image canvas to move the next word to the line below.